# OneToMany Relation with reference on a third table?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I got two entities with a simple OneToMany relation and anything works as expected.

The user entity:

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vita", mappedBy="owner")
     */
}
```

and the vita entity:

```
class Vita {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="vitas")
     */
}
```

So far, so good. But now I changed the vita entity and added the meta entity with a OneToOne relation. This entity knows the owner and other stuff, but the vita does not have longer a owner property.

What I am looking for is the oppotunity to use the third table as reference. Is there a common doctrine way? Something like that?

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vita", mappedBy="meta.owner")
     */
}
```

EDIT:

```
User
- id
- username
- password

Vita
- id
- meta_id
- [other fields]

Meta
- id
- owner_id (User)
- modifier_id (User)
- [other fields]
```

- One User has many Vita
- One Vita has one Meta

First the owner_id was a property of vita and now it moved into meta.

Comment: Can you create a simple graph of relationship? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. What's a meta? What's a vita? Is a meta a user?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I edited my question and I hope you'll see what I meant.

Comment: I'm quite sure that `mappedBy` cannot be used as a path (that is to point some other entity)

Comment: Yes, I allready tried it and thats the reason why I am looking for another solution here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the relationship schema, it should look like this:

```
class User {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Meta", mappedBy="owner")
     */
    protected $metasOwned;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Meta", mappedBy="modifier")
     */
    protected $metasModified;

}

class Vita {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Meta", inversedBy="vita")
     */
    protected $meta;

}

class Meta {

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="metasOwned")
     */
    protected $owner;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="metasModified")
     */
    protected $modifier;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Vita", mappedBy="meta")
     */
    protected $vita;

}
```

Notice that variable names correlate with the inverse-side of the relationships.

Then you just run the command

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Your/AwesomeBundle/Entity
```

and it will create getters & setters for you and you will be all set.

`Your/AwesomeBundle/Entity`: the real path is or could be `src/Your/AwesomeBundle/Entity`.

Comment: That of course far too easy.. :) The meta entity is independent of any other entities. The purpose is, to store repeating fields like owner in a separate table, no matter which type the parent entity is. So sad but true, that not a solution for my problem.

Comment: You basically want to map a User to a Vita through the Meta object? I mean unless you manage a new association there will always be 2 joins to do to be able to get vitas owned by a user.
The solution above is definitely the way to go and you could add a convenient method to the `User` object that fetches `Vitas` using the `getMetasOwned()`

Comment: The meta entity can belong to every other entity where I need this kind of information. When I go this way, I lost all advantages for what the meta entity is meant.

EDIT: The meta has currently 8 fields which I do not want to implement in each other item.

Comment: So Meta stands for metadata which is data that can define multiple different entities. Create a Meta [Doctrine Mapped SuperClass](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) and make every other entities extend it. Don't even bother with associations because it will not scale well (I tried it).

Comment: That sounds good, but here the same problem. The parentclass has to know its children. Maybe I must find another way :(

Comment: What would you want to do from the parent class? Every class that extends Meta would have access to its methods however the methods' scope will only be the entity rather than a set of entities.

Comment: Ok, that could be a kind of compromise and solves that problem. despite it is a "is-a" and not a "has-a" relation. I am not uses with doctrine inheritance. My meta entity would be the parent class with its own table and id in database and all other objects just extending it in common oop-style? The meta-id is important for other things. And whats about the configuration in meta about the childclasses? There are a lot of completely different type which use the metadata.